# How would I programatically add items to my menu in in activity_main_drawer.xml

Tags: java, android

I have this activity_main_drawer.xml file containing my drawer to my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cityAdd"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Add City" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cityList"
        android:title="Cities">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="I want to add these items"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>

</group>

</menu>
```

I am trying to reference my menu through Java so I could programmatically add items to my drawer while my app is running.  This is the method(I think that's what it's called I'm still a noob) :

```
  private void addMenuItemNavMenuDrawer(String added) {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    menu.add(added);
}
```

The problem is the items are not being added to the menu making this code useless.

If any other parts of my code are needed I will be happy to share. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What problems are you having, exactly?

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry about that. I edited the code adding in the problem.

Comment: Well, that code should at least add an item to the root menu. If that's not happening, then there are other problems that we can't determine from just the given snippets.

Comment: When you say, getMenu(), you're actually getting the root menu and not the menu inside cityList item!

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was due to me not understanding static and non-static variables that I created earlier in my code.